# how to correctly insert random number in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a problem with filling Linked list with generated random numbers, the output of my list is always empty, i want to fill linked list with n elements that user enters.

I was following by one of the tutorial, did everything the same, but i think that i might miss something. Will appreciate your help.

```
struct Node
{
    int number;
    Node *next;
};


void FirstEl(Node *&first, Node *&last, int number)
{
    Node *list = new Node;
    list->number = number;
    list->next = NULL;
    first = list;
    last = list;
};

bool isEmpty(Node *first)
{
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

void Insert(Node *&first, Node *&last, int number)
{
    if (isEmpty(first))
    {
        FirstEl(first, last, number);
    }
    else {
        Node *list = new Node;
        list->number = number;
        list->next = NULL;
        last->next = list;
        last = list;

    }
}

void ShowList(Node *current)
{

    if (isEmpty(current))
    {
        cout << "List is empty\n";
    }
    else {

        cout << "List: \n\n";

        while (current != NULL)
        {
            cout << current->number << "\n";
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{

int menu = 0, n = 0, number;

    Node *first = NULL;
    Node *last = NULL;
    cout << "Amount of element in List: ";
    cin >> n;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        number = (rand() % 10000 + 100);
        Insert(first, last, number);

    }
   ShowList(first);
}
```

Comment: Your `isEmpty` function does not explicitly return anything if the list is not empty. (A good compiler should warn you of this.) So in that case, it returns the default boolean value, which appears to be `true`. So the list always appears to be empty.

Comment: `IsEmpty` must always return something, otherwise your program is undefined. Write `return first == NULL;` instead of complicating things with conditionals.

Comment: @Beta It doesn't return a default value, it's undefined.

Comment: @molbdnilo: I stand corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `return false` to `isEmpty` function in case the condition doesn't exist.